# How do I perform batch insert with Playframewok JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I need to parse a very large file and store the resulting entities in a database.
I am expecting up to 150k records per file and would liek to process those in batches.

Is there a way to perform batch insert of a Play entity with JPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save memory you must make sure that the session is cleared regularly, so

```
Customer.em().getTransaction().begin(); 
for ( int i=1; i<=100000; i++ ) {
   ....
   myCustomer.save();
   if (i%1000==0) { 
       //Customer.em().getTransaction().commit();           
       Customer.em().flush(); 
       Customer.em().clear();
       //Customer.em().getTransaction().begin(); 
   }
}
Customer.em().getTransaction().commit();
```

How ever you can improve your performance if you optimize the batch size
`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 100`

You can simply add the last line to the `application.conf`, all hibernate.* properties go directly to hibernate. See the code of the `JPAPlugin` for details.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does it matter if the flush and clear happen after commit and begin?   What is the impact of the hibernate batch size = 100 if the transcation is committed every 1000 iterations?

Comment: Hm I think you are right, you don't need to handle the transaction. flush and clear should be enough.
About the batchsize: As far as I know this decides how many statements send to the database directly. Meaning with a batchsize from 1 you have 1000 times network io, with 100 you only have 10, if you want to insert 1000 entries.

Comment: Will the batch size affect the lifecycle of entities for the application? i.e. does calling MyEntity.save() with batch size of 100 means that those are only actually persisted every 100th times?

Comment: Well MyEntity.save() only set a flag in hibernate. Only flush send it to the database. But I'm unsure if the jdbc-driver will cache then again. I only have the experience with fetchsize for plain jdbc, which has a really small default. If you increase it it will have a big impact on performance. So I would recommend to make some test and look on the memory consumption and the duration time.

Answer (score 1):

As Play uses Hibernate under the hood, you should be able to use the standard batch processing that Hibernate uses. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html

However, Play automatically manages transactions for you, so, if you need to prevent Play from interfering with the Transaction management, you can annotate your method with `@play.db.jpa.NoTransaction`.

You can read more about Play's JPA and transaction support here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/jpa

Comment: The processing takes place in a Job and I am not sure if the @NoTransaction can be applied. I tried calling the following lines every 1000 iterations which seems to give me constant time/memory/processing:                          Customer.em().getTransaction().commit();
        Customer.em().getTransaction().begin();
        Customer.em().flush();
        Customer.em().clear();